# Why is the following method of finding out a conserved quantity wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let a system be defined by $\dot{x}=y; \dot{y}=f(x).$ And let $E(x,y)$ be a conserved quantity of the system. Then
$$
\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{x}}\dot{x}+\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{y}}\dot{y}=0.
$$
My question is why cannot I just rewrite this equation as
$$
\frac{\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{x}}}{{\frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{y}}}}=\frac{-\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}.
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}.
$$

Now the separation of variables would easily give me a curve in $(x,y)$ space which can also be thought of as a conserved quantity. Looking at examples in Strogatz, I figured out that this  method is wrong, but I am unable to find out why?

Comment: $\frac{\partial_x E}{\partial_y E}\neq\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain this a little? or refer me to an appropriate post?

Comment: Actually, I get it now. Should have guessed it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is already answered in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777277/why-is-the-following-method-of-finding-out-a-conserved-quantity-wrong#comment7776936_3777277).  The mistake is that in general,

$$\tag{1}\frac{\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial E}{\partial y} }\neq \frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}.$$

Probably the confusion comes from a similar results (that is used in ODE a lot) where

$$ \frac{ y' }{x'} = \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}.$$
Thus is essentially Chain rule in one dimension. But when $E$ has two variables, the chain rule is more complicated and we do not have (1).